# Confusion with a type that has members char *ptr; size_t used; size_t size?

Tags: c, syntax

I structures like the following

```
typedef struct 
{

    char *ptr;

    size_t used;
    size_t size;

} buffer;

typedef struct 
{

    buffer *request;
    buffer *uri;

    buffer *orig_uri;

    http_method_t  http_method;
    http_version_t http_version;

    buffer *request_line;

    /* strings to the header */
    buffer *http_host; /* not alloced */
    const char   *http_range;
    const char   *http_content_type;
    const char   *http_if_modified_since;
    const char   *http_if_none_match;

    array  *headers;

    /* CONTENT */
    size_t content_length; /* returned by strtoul() */

    /* internal representation */
    int     accept_encoding;

    /* internal */
    buffer *pathinfo;
} request;
```

Now if I want to write(in a text file) the value of the member "http_host" which belongs to the structure "request". The member "http_host" is actually a "buffer" type, how should I write it? Kindly explain with the syntax.

Comment: What do you mean by "write"?  Do you mean display it on the console?  And what is `ptr`?  Is it a string of characters?

Comment: The question isn't really very clear.

Comment: I missed a point there, I meant I wanted to write in a file. ptr is a char pointer.

Comment: The point still isn't very clear. Did you write this program yourself, or are you trying to understand it? What is stored in the `ptr` in `buffer`? A piece of text? If so, is it a C string (zero terminated) or is the text length stored in `used`? Questions like that spring to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
// open the file
FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.txt");

// print
fprintf(fp, "%s\n", http_host->ptr);

// close the file
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: I tried it before, but was not giving the right way. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have allocated and initialized all relevant structures you can go by this:

```
request * req = malloc(sizeof(request));
buffer * buf = malloc(sizeof(buffer));
/* initialize buffer */
.......................
req->http_host = buf;
FILE * fp = fopen("file");
fprintf(fp,"ptr %s\n", req->http_host->ptr);
fprintf (fp,"size %d\n", req->http_host->size);
fprintf (fp,"used %d\n", req->http_host->used);
```

if you want to know something else(that is if i'm misunderstanding your question, please elaborate your question)

Comment: you always have fprintf()...just FILE * fp; fp = fopen("file");